# Remove specific letter and adjacent string values regex

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, case-sensitive

I am looking at a list of strings that are space separated. I am trying to find parts of string that contain a lower case "n" letter that is **not** next to an uppercase letter, then remove the lowercase "n" and any adjacent letter/number. Example:

```
before = ["23n 5T R3",
"4T 3R 2+ 2-",
"-2 +3RF n3",
"Nn1 L9 3+ n",
"un2 L0 -9 e"]
```

I am trying to get an output as:

```
after = ["5T R3",
"4T 3R 2+ 2-",
"-2 +3RF",
"Nn1 O9 3+",
"L0 -9 e"]
```

I am not exactly sure how to go about starting this regex condition. Apologies if its a bit tough one.

Comment: Running "[re.sub(r'([\b.n\b|\b.n\b"]+)','', x) for x in before]" removes all lowercase "n" letters, even if adjacent to a capital letter.

Comment: My question is downvoted without guidance on what doesn't look right :) Maybe the admins can provide some input here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to acheive it.

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/HKi4tp/2

**Pattern:** `\b\S*(?<![A-Z])n\S*\b ?`

**Breakdown:**

- `\b\S*`and `\S*\b`: Match any no of *non-space* characters at start and end of word. (*Note:* Based on your need, `\S` can be replaced with `\w` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]`)
- `(?<![A-Z])n`: match `n` not preceded by `[A-Z]`
- `?`: match an optional *space* after the word
- In substituition, an empty string will delete it

Comment: That's an amazing explanation and way to demo it. Thanks a lot @Prasanna!